# How to get information about all available images to create vm instance through API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-apis-explorer

I am creating a sort of Demand entry App in which I want to populate metadata(regions, zones, images etc) through google API. I am calling this API, for example, `https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/global/images` with my project id. But I got 200 responses and don't see any data.

Thanks
Kovi

```
https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/global/images

{
  "id": "projects/sap-iidc-cde/global/images",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/sap-iidc-cde/global/images",
  "kind": "compute#imageList"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API only returns custom images available to the specified project. A custom image is one that the Project created.

If you want to list images in other projects such as Debian or Windows, you need to use their project ID.

Well known images projects:

```
centos-cloud, coreos-cloud, debian-cloud, cos-cloud, rhel-cloud, rhel-sap-cloud, suse-cloud, suse-sap-cloud, ubuntu-os-cloud, windows-cloud, windows-sql-cloud
```

To list images use the SDK CLI. This will show you the various Project IDs associated with each image.

```
gcloud compute images list
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently getting public image list is not available in `image.list` method.
There is a ticket asking to support public image but don't have recent updates.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64718267

A workaround could be to curl https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/images?project= and then parse the response to get image ids

Otherwise, the `gcloud` command is the best bet at the moment. you can run this command within your program and parse the output to get list of images.